# Python - Pandas, group by time intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, delta

Having the following DF:

```
group_id                timestamp
       A  2020-09-29 06:00:00 UTC
       A  2020-09-29 08:00:00 UTC
       A  2020-09-30 09:00:00 UTC
       B  2020-09-01 04:00:00 UTC
       B  2020-09-01 06:00:00 UTC
```

I would like to count the deltas between records using all groups, not counting deltas between groups. Result for the above example:

```
delta       count
    2           2
   25           1
```

Explanation: In group A the deltas are

```
06:00:00 -> 08:00:00 (2 hours)
08:00:00 -> 09:00:00 on the next day (25 hours)
```

And in group B:

```
04:00:00 -> 06:00:00 (2 hours)
```

How can I achieve this using Python Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for differencies per groups, convert to seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), divide by `3600` for hours and last count values by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with convert `Series` to `2 columns DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby("group_id")['timestamp']
        .diff()
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .div(3600)
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('delta')
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   delta  count
0    2.0      2
1   25.0      1
```

Comment: Thanks for that excellent solution! What do I need to change in order to count the diff always from the first record in the group? I.E in group A (2,27).

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
df_out = df.groupby("group_id").diff().groupby("timestamp").size()

# convert to dataframe
df_out = df_out.to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={"timestamp": "delta", 0: "count"})
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)
            delta  count
0 0 days 02:00:00      2
1 1 days 01:00:00      1
```

The `NaT`'s (missing values) produced by groupby-diff were ignored automatically.

To represent timedelta in hours, just call `total_seconds()` method.

```
df_out["delta"] = df_out["delta"].dt.total_seconds() / 3600

print(df_out)
   delta  count
0    2.0      2
1   25.0      1
```