# Python - Pandas, count time diff from first record in a group

Tags: python, pandas

In continue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966109/python-pandas-group-by-time-intervals/64966547#64966547)
Having the following DF:

```
group_id                timestamp
       A  2020-09-29 06:00:00 UTC
       A  2020-09-29 08:00:00 UTC
       A  2020-09-30 09:00:00 UTC
       B  2020-09-01 04:00:00 UTC
       B  2020-09-01 06:00:00 UTC
```

I would like to count the deltas between records using all groups, not counting deltas between groups. Result for the above example:

```
delta       count
    2           2
   27           1
```

Explanation: In group A the deltas are

```
06:00:00 -> 08:00:00 (2 hours)
08:00:00 -> 09:00:00 on the next day (27 hours from the first event)
```

And in group B:

```
04:00:00 -> 06:00:00 (2 hours)
```

How can I achieve this using Python Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst idea is use custom lambda function with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for cumulative sum:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df1 = (df.groupby("group_id")['timestamp']
        .apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds().cumsum())
        .div(3600)
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('delta')
        .reset_index(name='count')
        )
print (df1)
   delta  count
0    2.0      2
1   27.0      1
```

Or add another `groupby` with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df1 = (df.groupby("group_id")['timestamp']
        .diff()
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .div(3600)
        .groupby(df['group_id'])
        .cumsum()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('delta')
        .reset_index(name='count')
        )
print (df1)
   delta  count
0    2.0      2
1   27.0      1
```

Another idea is subtract first values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), but for remove first rows with `0` is added filter by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df1 = (df['timestamp'].sub(df.groupby("group_id")['timestamp'].transform('first'))
         .loc[df['group_id'].duplicated()]
         .dt.total_seconds()
         .div(3600)
         .value_counts()
         .rename_axis('delta')
         .reset_index(name='count')
        )
print (df1)
   delta  count
0    2.0      2
1   27.0      1
```